# Aliased atomic operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, undefined-behavior, unions

Say that I have the following struct and union:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
   std::atomic<int> a;
   std::atomic<int> b;
};

union Bar
{
   std::atomic<Foo> x;
   Foo y;
} bar;
```

Assuming Foo is always lock free, is it safe to perform (64-bit) atomic loads from `bar x` while concurrently modifying the 32-bit member variables of `bar.y`?

Comment: `std::atomic<Foo> x;` is ill-formed. because Foo is not copy/move constructible/assignable. Newer versions of gcc/clang won't even compile it.

Comment: Regardless of synchronizations, it is UB to read from an inactive member of a union.

Comment: Assume the necessary reinterpret_casts have been made ;^)

Comment: There is no cast that can make reading from an inactive union member legal.

Comment: @bolov: I find it absurd that the C++ Standard fails to define any reasonable means of achieving useful semantics that were achievable easily in C 46 years ago, and which almost all implementations naturally support, with consistent semantics, when optimizations and diagnostics are disabled.